# How can I get audio frame buffer from mediarecorder class

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Is there any way can I get the audio buffer after start recording like we can get if we use AudioRecorder class instead of MediaRecoredr class.

I am using MediaRecorder like below

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(bitRate);
    recorder.setVideoSize(screenSize.get(videoResolutionIndex).getWidth(),
            screenSize.get(videoResolutionIndex).getHeight());
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(audioSamplingRate);
    recorder.setOutputFile(videoPath);
    recorder.setOrientationHint(currentViewOrientation);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("prepare IOException:" + e);
    }

    recorder.start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a Java code?

Comment: Yes, Android java code.